# How do I define an Lilypond/Scheme alist as cons of two a lists?

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

I have pitch names defined as a alist in Lilypond as below and it works fine. 
\version "2.18.2"

```
pitchname = #`(
                (saa . , (ly:make-pitch -1 0 NATURAL))
                (raa . , (ly:make-pitch -1 1 FLAT))


                (sa . , (ly:make-pitch -1 0 NATURAL))
                (ri . , (ly:make-pitch -1 1 FLAT))
                (ga . , (ly:make-pitch -1 2 NATURAL))                 
                )                               

#(ly:parser-set-note-names parser pitchname)

musicA = \relative sa' { sa4 ri ga sa ri ga sa ri ga ri saa ga ri sa ga raa  }

\score {\musicA}
```

I would like to define the variable pitchname as sum/join/append/cons of two a lists, as below:

```
     firstpart = #`(
                    (saa . , (ly:make-pitch -1 0 NATURAL))
                    (raa . , (ly:make-pitch -1 1 FLAT))
                   )

    secondpart = #'(
                     (sa . , (ly:make-pitch -1 0 NATURAL))
                    (ri . , (ly:make-pitch -1 1 FLAT))
                    (ga . , (ly:make-pitch -1 2 NATURAL))               
                    )
```

and combine the two, say:

```
pitchname = (cons #firstpart #secondpart)
```

The last statement combining the two parts is not working. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `cons` does *not* concatenate lists. It *constructs* list. The result of `(cons head tail)` is a list whose first element is `head` then followed by the elements of `tail`.

Answer (score 1):

```
pitchname = #(append firstpart secondpart)
```

Comment: Tried that - says error: not a symbol pitchmane = (append #firstpart #secondpart)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code.

1. As others noted, what you really want to do is `append` the alists.  (Also, you forgot the leading `#` to escape from Lilypond to Scheme.)  For comparision, this is what using `cons` instead would do. Note how the elements don't end up at the same nesting depth:

```
    pitchname = `(((saa . , (ly:make-pitch -1 0 NATURAL))
                   (raa . , (ly:make-pitch -1 1 FLAT)))
                  (sa . , (ly:make-pitch -1 0 NATURAL))
                  (ri . , (ly:make-pitch -1 1 FLAT))
                  (ga . , (ly:make-pitch -1 2 NATURAL)))
```

2. Your second list is quoted (straight apostrophe) instead of quasiquoted (backtick). You do want those `make-pitch` calls to be evaluated, so you can't go around the quasiquoting here.